# New passport for stamping

Tags: visas

I recently got my passport reissued as it was damaged a little. Now am planning to apply for Schengen Visa. As the new passport will not have any stamping. Should I be sending both the passports for Schengen Stamping or just the new one? Please advise

Comment: Did they ask you to send in the old passport?

Comment: No, the have not asked me. I have not applied for the visa yet. Am worried that they might have an issue with and reject. So, wanted to know if thats an issue.
Thanks

Comment: Answer the application questions truthfully, and submit the documents the application asks for.

Answer (score 1):

A Schengen Visa application asks for your current passport regardless of earlier passports and stamps in earlier passports.

If they require further information they will contact you and ask for it, simply fill in the form and answer all questions truthfully.